# What is meaning of this newspaper extract?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, british-english

> There have been exceptions — the Nepali Maoists, for example, managed to partake in power after peacefully ending the civil war — but if the Indian Maoists’ denunciation of these steps taken by their Nepali counterparts are any indication, such a step does not seem to be in the offing.

I am unable to comprehend the meaning of the last line.

Comment: Where is this extract taken from?

Comment: @Alex The Hindu.

Comment: What is it that you don’t understand? Do you know what each of the individual words mean?

Comment: What is meant by Maoist denunciation?What is meant by such a step in the offing?

Comment: Which part is troubling you? The Maoist denunciation is simply a denunciation by a Maoist. Do you know what a denunciation and a Maoist are individually? And the same for the second part.

Comment: For _in the offing_, see https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/in-the-offing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There have been exceptions — the Nepali Maoists, for example, managed to partake in power after peacefully ending the civil war — but if the Indian Maoists’ denunciation of these steps taken by their Nepali counterparts are any indication, such a step does not seem to be in the offing.

The clause

> [T]he Nepali Maoists, for example, managed to partake in power after peacefully ending the civil war[.]

refers to a positive move.

The passage says if the Indian Maoists denunciate positive moves like these, such a step, of partaking in power, seems unlikely to happen soon.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/partake

> partake verb [I] (TAKE PART)
> old-fashioned or formal
> to become involved with or take part in something:
> She was happy to partake in the festivities.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in-the-offing

> in the offing
> going to happen soon